# Adding image on mouse click is not adding image on correct co-ordinates

Tags: javascript, html

[image]I am using pdf.js to view the pdf, and adding canvas over the top of the each page to add image on click. Images are adding on mouse click but its not on exact position..

```
  $('.page').on('click', function(e) {
        console.log("fgdfgdfg")

        console.log(e)
      if($("#hotspotTool").hasClass('active')){
    var pageIndex = window.PDFViewerApplication.pdfViewer.currentPageNumber;
    var page = window.PDFViewerApplication.pdfViewer.getPageView(pageIndex);
        if ($(e.target).parent().hasClass('page')) {
       var pid = $(e.target).parent().attr("id");
       console.log(pid)
        var canvas=document.getElementById(pid).getElementsByClassName("annotationLayer_svg")[0]
        console.log(canvas)
        var canv_id = $(canvas).attr('id')
        if(canvas){
        count++
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        base_image = new Image();
        base_image.src = '/images/dot.png';
        base_image.id="hotspot"+count
        base_image.draggable="true"
        console.log(base_image)
        var x = e.offsetX - base_image.width/2,
        y = e.offsetY - base_image.height/2;
        console.log(x,y)

  ctx.drawImage(base_image,x,y);
   ctx.save();

  $("#hotspotTool").removeClass("active");
    $('#hotspotmodel').modal('show');
    $('#submit').on('click', function() {

      $(this).data('clicked', true);
      $("#hotspotform").valid();
      if( $("#hotspotform").valid()){
        $('#hotspotmodel').modal('hide');
        var page_value = document.getElementById("pagelink").value
        var spot_link = window.location.href+"page="+page_value
        var anchor = document.createElement("A");
        anchor.appendChild(base_image)
        anchor.setAttribute("href", spot_link);
        }
      });
    }
    }
  }
})
```

How can I able to add image on mouse click on exact position

Comment: The event (represented here by `e`) does not have an `offsetX` or `offsetY` properties. You should change those to `clientX` and `clientY`

Comment: I have added image .Actually I have clicked on top but image is adding on below. Ok i will try client

Comment: If i am changed to client Image is not getting added